# Getting attributeerror 'str' object has no attribute 'items' while creating exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Python 3.7 and trying to create exe for my python script using pyinstaller. When I am running pyinstaller TextSummarize.py I am getting error after a while,

> attributeerror 'str' object has no attribute 'items'.

Due to this the process is not being completed.

Looking at the error itseems that its due to some module in the site-package of PyInstaller. I executed the

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

but it did not help.

The code is small pasting it below. It asks user for input text and outputs the summarized text. So I want to create a exe file for this.

```
from gensim.summarization import summarize
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
top = Tk()

def process():
    sentence=Entry.get(E1)
    ans=summarize(sentence)
    Entry.insert(E4,0,ans)
    print(ans)

top.title("Text Summarizer")
L1 = Label(top, text="Text Summarizer",).grid(row=0,column=1)
L2 = Label(top, text="Enter text to summerize",).grid(row=1,column=0)
L3 = Label(top, text="Answer",).grid(row=4,column=0)
E1 = Entry(top, bd=5)
E1.grid(row=1, column=1)
E4 = Entry(top, bd =5)
E4.grid(row=4,column=1)
B=Button(top, text ="Submit",command = process).grid(row=5,column=1,)

top.mainloop()
```

Below I am pasting last part of the output where error is occurring when I execute pyinstaller TextSummarize.py:

```
target_attr_names=None, level=level, edge_attr=edge_File 
"c:\users\rajerai.oradev\appdata\local\continuum\
ges\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 14
target_module = self._load_tail(target_package, targ
File "c:\users\rajerai.oradev\appdata\local\continuum\
ges\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 16
submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, su
File "c:\users\rajerai.oradev\appdata\local\continuum\
ges\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 260, in _safe_
hook_module.pre_safe_import_module(hook_api)
File "c:\users\rajerai.oradev\appdata\local\continuum\
ges\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-setupt
", line 34, in pre_safe_import_module
for real_module_name, six_module_name in real_to_six
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

This error occurs after partial execution i.e dist folder is created and TextSummarize.spec file is created.

Any help is appreciated to resolve this error.

Comment: What is the command you used to create the exe?

Comment: I used pyinstaller TextSummarizer.py to create the exe. I also tried pyinstaller --onefile TextSummarizer.py but I get the same error.

Comment: I solved the issue by updating setuptools in conda. Again i got a error for PyQt5. So I installed PyQt5. Finally the exe was successfully created.